# Printing an unwanted symbol in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I have to make a python script for a school project that converts decimal numbers to binary numbers. I was able to write the code but every time when executed it prints the binary number and the "%" symbol at the end.
How can I remove the "%" symbol from when it is printing it?

This is the script:

```
first=int(input("input a decimal number to convert to a binary: "))
toBase=2
first2=first
char=0
char2=0
char3=0

while first2!=0:
    first2//=2
    char+=1

binNum=[0]*char

while first!=0:
   rem=first%2
   first//=2
   binNum[char2]=rem
   char2+=1

for loop in range(char):
   char3-=1
   print(binNum[char3],end="")
```

As an example, when I enter `128` in the beginning instead of getting `10000000` as a result I get `10000000%`

I am currently using python 3.7.4

Comment: `print(bin(int(input())))`

Comment: After the loop, do `print()`.  Because you aren't printing newlines in your print statements, your terminal prompt is being rendered on the same line.

Comment: I ran your code and I did not find any `%` symbol appearing. What version of python are you on?

Comment: I am using python 3.7.4

Comment: Ah, maybe the issue is something else. Append `print("")` at the end of your code. Not inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code and run it.
it was Ok and the problem you mentioned didn't happen.

But one more thing:
you can use this method:

```
bin(128)
```

and the output will be: 0b10000000
then you can simply omit 0b like:

```
a=bin(128)
print(a[2:])
```

[The Qutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFY6r.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like below:

```
deci_num = int(input("input a decimal number to convert to a binary: "))
bin = ''
while(deci_num):
     if(deci_num % 2 == 1):
          bin += '1'
     else:
          bin += '0'
     deci_num //= 2
print (bin[::-1])
```